# jquery multiple buttons movedown with a delay for each button

Tags: jquery, animation, slidedown

I have this html:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">button1</a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">button2</a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">button3</a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">button4</a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">button5</a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">button6</a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">button7</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider">
</div>
```

and i want to do a movedown effect to each button with a delay when the page load.
I've tried with jquery.slideDown and I didn't get the expected result. Then I`ve tried with .animate but the buttons are moving all at once without delay beetwen them.

This is what I've get with .slideDown: http://www.specter.uv.ro

this is what I've tried with animate: www.specter.uv.ro/index2.html

```
var seq = $('li').show(), li = 0;
(function() {
  $(seq[li++]).animate({'margin-top':'20px'}, 300, arguments.callee);
})();
```

I don't know where to put delay.

I am new with jQuery.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlideDown provides a callback method to run when the current animation is finished. If your delay is the same length as the animation, you could try something like this (assumes they're hidden from the start):

```
$(function() {
  $("#navbar li:first-child").slideDown(200, slideNext);
});
function slideNext() {
  $(this).next().slideDown(500, slideNext);
}
```

You could also try this (which is probably more what you're looking for):

```
$(function() {
  $("#navbar li").each(function(ind) {
    setTimeout("$($('#navbar li')[" + ind + "]).slideDown(200);", ind * 100);
  });
});
```

The `100` in `ind * 100` is the delay between each.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.  Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rpQF/)

```
$(function() {
    var delay = 0;
    var duration = 2000;
    $("#navbar li").hide().each(function() {
       $(this).delay(delay).slideDown(duration);
       delay += 1000; 
    });
});
```

If, as Zain's comment suggests, you don't want a different delay for each button, you can replace the bulk of the above with:

```
$(#navbar li").hide().delay(delay).slideDown(duration);
```

Comment: I dont think this is what @Sp3ct3R asked for, your script will slow down the animation in each loop.

Comment: @Zain, hrm.  The OP says *but the buttons are moving all at once without delay between them.*

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I misunderstood. my mistake. +1

Comment: sorry for my english... I couldn't explain good enought look at this picture: http://img213.imageshack.us/i/movedown.jpg/ moving button from top:0px to about 50px and make a delay beetwen buttons

Comment: ok I've discovered that the inline display is the problem of margin-top that I used to move the li verticaly... if you can provide another way to move it verticaly please help me. And thanks for the quickness of the response. What you provided up here is what I've done here: http://www.specter.uv.ro/index.html

Comment: @Sp3ct3R, not sure what you're asking.  Why do you need another way?

Comment: @rchern look at this picture http://www.img213.imageshack.us/i/movedown.jpg i want this: first button start at top:0px and slidedown to top:30px in 300ms. With a 100ms delay the second button slidedown from top:0px to top:30px and so on. Forget my script just make a menu like what i explained here.

Comment: You already linked the picture.  It didn't clear anything up the 2nd time.  Either you want slideDown or you want to use animate.  The principle is the same.  It basically sounds like you want the delay to be a different number.  So change it?

Comment: ok i finaly did what i wanted http://specter.uv.ro/index3.html but the effect is too sharp i want it smoother and the fadein i added i want to start at the same time with the slide and i want an easing at the end of slide. if it is posible. sorry if i am too fastidious :D